# Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to fill my database using the model method `create` like this:

```
public function registerDevice($command) {
    $deviceId = $command->deviceId;
    $deviceToken = $command->deviceToken;

    $this->deviceId = $deviceId;
    $this->deviceToken = $deviceToken;

    Device::create(array('device_id' => $deviceId, 'device_token' => $deviceToken));
    $this->raise(new DeviceWasRegistered($this));
    return $this;
}
```

The entry is being made, but only the timestamps are being updates. The value fields are empty. No error coming up or something else is failing. But the values I want to put into the db are there if I var_dump the variables.

Do I miss something out?

Comment: Can you show the model? You probably didn't fill `protected $fillable`

Answer (score 2):

In order for the create method to work, you need to put your two fields in the `$fillable` array on the model. So make sure you have this in your model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'device_id',
    'device_token',
];
```

You can read more about the `create` method and mass assignment at http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment.

Comment: Haaaaaaaaa!! I had deviceId and deviceToken in there!! No it works perfectly well!

Comment: I'm not sure but isn't the fillable attribute deciding which attributes get **mass assigned**? He is assigning them manually so this shouldn't be a problem. If he'd be doing `Device::create($request->input())` and he's missing fields in the fillable then it'd not work - Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Krenor nope, read the code again. He's doing `$this->deviceId` and `$this->deviceToken` in the controller, and then passing through an array to the `create` method, hence mass assigning.

Comment: @Phroggyy yeah, you were right. I thought MA was for `Input/Request::all()` and not for create, too! **EDIT:** For clearing things up, yes I meant using the `all()` method when using `create()` or `fill()`

Comment: @Krenor `Request::all()` simply returns an array, so that has nothing to do with mass assignment. Mass assignment in Laravel is when you pass through an array on either object construction, or when using `create` or `update`, or using the `fill` method explicitly.